# What is the significance of 'root' in getEntityRecords?

Tags: block-editor

I've gone through the documentation and the source code but I couldn't understand.

I have 2 queries:

`getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post' );` and `getEntityRecords( 'root', 'user' )`.

1. Why does the 2nd query require `root` as the 1st argument?
2. What does it mean?
3. How to determine when to use it?

The doc describes the parameters of `getEntityRecords` as following:

**Parameters:**

- state **Object**: State tree
- kind **string**: Entity kind.
- name **string**: Entity name.
- query **?Object**: Optional terms query.

4. Are `postType` and `root` both state trees?
5. How does `state` relate to `kind` while referring to [entities.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/core-data/src/entities.js)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to note is that `post` is a kind/sub-type of the post types entity, all posts regardless of type share the same table and general data structure and fields etc.

This contrasts with other major entity types such as comments or users.

However, what if there is no kind or sub-type? What if your entity is a user? What would you put as the entity kind/sub-type? There is only 1 kind of user! So you go one level up, and that's where `root` comes from.

It's also useful to know that entities are very related to the REST API and endpoints, and that this is the only connection to the PHP side of things. Entities only exist in the WP javascript packages. It's possible to use the REST API and javascript without referring to entities on the frontend, but if you're working with the block editor it's highly relevant.